# What's the status of alternative full node implementations?

Tags: network, nodes

In "[Does running an alternative full node implementation benefit the Bitcoin network?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/12820/214)", I asked about running an alternative full node implementation for the benefit of the Bitcoin network.

What is the current status of different alternative full node implementations with regard to

- maturity (alpha/beta/stable)
- performance
- compatibility tests
- code review
- suitability for different purposes:

  - experimentation
  - merchants
  - as a wallet
  - as a lightweight wallet back-end
  - solely for the benefit of the network?

**Update:** Moved the list of implementations into an answer.

Comment: This question requires a good answer to be too long for this format. However, I think the [Client overview page of the bitcoin.it-wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Clients) might be at least partially what you are looking for.

Comment: @Murch You must consider that StackExchange answers usually appear first and foremost while searching, and that an answer here might attract more interest than a blog post could. The SE format is rich enough, I guess the limitations are engagement and expertise - i.e., nobody cares, or who cares doesn't know.

Comment: @BrunoKim Correct. Unfortunately, engagement on the Bitcoin.SE is somewhat at a low, so I would expect information that has to be constantly updated to fall behind quickly, i.e. in this case I think it is better to link to the bitcoin wiki (not a blog post) instead of duplicating their effort.

Comment: @Murch I couldn't find any wiki page on bitcoin.it about full node implementations, and the tables there don't seem to have a column for that either. In your opinion, should I create a list of full node implementations on the wiki instead of maintaining this list here?

Comment: Well, if someone starts doing it here, that would be marvelous of course, I was just thinking that there might be more people using bitcoin.it actively than bitcoin.SE.

However, I am not sure, are you currently collecting information in the Question? It might be better if you created an answer instead for the answer part. :) If you need help, I am up for it, I usually hang out in the Bitcoin chat when I am online.

Comment: The answer to this question will change radically over time, (and may actually be opinion-driven,) so I don't think this is a good place for this question.

Comment: In any case, the answer part of the question would make a good start for an answer.

Comment: It's not an answer, but I requested to be able to do my Masters Thesis about Bitcoin and if my proposal is accepted, I will be building a full node implementation in Dart. I've been building a [Dart Bitcoin library](https://github.com/dartcoin/dartcoin-lib) for the last few months.

Answer (score 11):

**Update:** [Coin Dance](https://coin.dance/) has an excellent table of node implementations with descriptions and links at the bottom of their [Bitcoin Nodes Summary](https://coin.dance/nodes) page.

---

Below are the implementations I've found. I'm not sure if all of them qualify as full nodes.

- [btcd](https://github.com/btcsuite/btcd#btcd)
  (in Go, by Conformal Systems LLC)
- [Bits of Proof](https://github.com/bitsofproof)
  (in Java, by bits of proof zrt.)
- [bitcoinj](https://bitcoinj.github.io/) has a
  [fully verifying mode](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=291581.msg3152092#msg3152092)
  (in Java, by Mike Hearn)
- [picocoin](https://github.com/jgarzik/picocoin)
  (in C, by Jeff Garzik)
- [libbitcoin](http://libbitcoin.dyne.org/) has an
  [example full node implementation](http://libbitcoin.dyne.org/doc/fullnode.html),
  also advertises to be a
  [completely independent and full Bitcoin stack](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=291581)
  albeit only pre-alpha proof-of-concept with no GUI
  (in C++, by Amir Taaki)
- [caesure](https://github.com/samrushing/caesure)
  (in Python, by Sam Rushing)
- [Electrum-server](https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum-server),
  uses bitcoind as a back-end
  (in Python, by thomasv@bitcointalk)
- [Ufasoft Coin](http://ufasoft.com/coin/)
  (in C++, only for Windows, by Ufasoft)
- [Bitcore](http://bitcore.io/) (in JavaScript. Note that it needs parts of Bitcoin Core to function)

(Sources: [Core Development Update #4](https://bitcoinfoundation.org/blog/?p=204) by Gavin Andresen, Jun 21 2013 on the Bitcoin Foundation blog; bitcointalk.org forums)

**Updated** bitcoinj and libbitcoin status (based on information from
[this bitcointalk thread](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=291581));
Electrum backend
**Added** Bitcore

Comment: I'd like to stress that miners must use bitcoind. If certain miners use different implementations it might cause forks in the blockchain. It's a complicated issue talked more in detail here http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/25254/why-dont-developers-switch-from-bitcoin-qt-to-a-cleaner-implementation

Comment: We also use our own implementation, in Go as well but distinct from btcd: http://www.blockcypher.com

Comment: @Matthieu Thanks for the information! Looks like it's only used internally by you and it isn't possible for others to run full nodes using your software?

Comment: @akaihola For now, but you can access it through the API and we will open source it when we're ready.

Comment: Should [NBitcoin](https://github.com/NicolasDorier/NBitcoin) be listed here too?

Comment: I think Hive uses Electrum-server as its backend? Is the API documented?